# Loading Mask orientation

Tags: sencha-touch

I have posted the similar question in :
[sencha touch forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?167854-Loading-Mask-orientation-problem)

But no answer yet :(

I'm facing orientation problem in the loading mask when I rotate my device to landscape (from portrait). It doesn't recalculate its position to fullscreen. I'm using Galaxy Tab for running my application.

Here is the screenshot :
[image]

I don't know whether it is some kind of sencha bug or not..
Could someone help me out of this case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you may attach screen shots now ;), and please elaborate "Problem"

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but I hope this will help.

Either

```
listeners : {
    orientationchange : function(context, orientation, width,height) {
        mask.hide();
        mask.show();
    }
}
```

Or

```
listeners : {
    orientationchange : function(context, orientation, width,height) {
        panel.docomponentlayout();
    }
}
```